# PDF links should open in new tab in mPDF library

Tags: php, html, drupal-7, mpdf

I want to open the links in new tab which are embedded in the pdf. I am using mPDF library in Drupal to generate pdf.
 I tried target="_blank" but its not working.this is the code actually i am using

```
<tr><td><a target="_blank" style="color: #fff;  text-decoration: none;" href="'.$course_url.'">' . $coursecertfiltered . '</a></td></tr>
```

Comment: what's the exact code that you're using

Comment: please find the code in question, just now i edited

Comment: I don't think PDFs support specifying a target.

Comment: Please Specify target="_blank" at the and of tag.. This might work in dynamic pdf's. like this :     <tr><td><a  style="color: #fff;  text-decoration: none;" href="'.$course_url.'" target="_blank">' . $coursecertfiltered . '</a></td></tr>

Answer (score -2):

If confident with Javascript, you may try:

```
<a onclick="openInNewTab('path-to-pdf-file');">Open in a new Tab</a>

<script>
  function openInNewTab(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
  }
</script>
```